# Firebase authentication exposes firebaseAuthToken, is it secure?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security, firebasesimplelogin

I'm trying to provide Google Login for my Firebase application. 
Following https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html

It appears that after a successful login, a user can be obtained, hence it could be for example stored in the Angular scope - e.g. $scope.loggedInUser. (Depending on your implementation, it doesn't have to be Angular)

My question is, is it a security risk that the user returned by Firebase with lots of authentication tokens can be exposed? 
The code is in Javascript, somehow hackers should be able to hijack and steal the user by embedding some code in a browser.

The bits that raise my concern are: accessToken, firebaseAuthToken

If it is a risk, how can we secure it?

---

Please refer to the code below for authentication and user data:

Here's the code for authentication:

```
authModule.controller( 'AuthController', [
  '$scope',
  '$firebase',
  function ( $scope, $firebase ) {
    var ref = new Firebase( 'https://test123.firebaseio.com' );

    var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin( ref, function ( error, user ) {
      if ( user ) {
        $scope.loggedInUser = user; // user has authenticated, this user contains security information
      }
    } );

    $scope.login = function () {
      auth.login( "google", {
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
      } );
    };
  }] );
```

What's contained in loggedInUser (this is just example data):

```
loggedInUser:  { 
    id: 7058267704789236427849
    uid: google:7058267704789236427849
    displayName: Joe Bloggs
    provider: google
    thirdPartyUserData:  { 
        id: 709139364278942374
        email: test@gmail.com
        verified_email: true
        name: Joe Bloggs
        given_name: Joe
        family_name: Bloggs
        link: https://plus.google.com/2672340913423423
        picture: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/.../photo.jpg
        gender: male
        locale: en-GB
     } 
    accessToken: W8k8dD6vvLEdlWa-dxkJD8lvWIwzea6m_86um8...
    email: test@gmail.com
    firebaseAuthToken: Q3Mjc4MzYsInYiOjAsImQiOnsiaWQiOiIxMDk0...
 }
```

Comment: I think posting access tokens on an open website is a bigger risk than on an Angular scope. I hope those aren't your real ones.

Comment: Considering you've already sent the credentials to the browser, it shouldn't make much impact wether you decide to store them in memory or not. If someone did manage to pull off a XSS attack and execute code in the user's browser they can steal those tokens wether they're saved or not as soon as the callback from `FirebaseSimpleLogin` is executed.

Comment: Thanks. These are not my real data :D

Comment: Good. I just have to ask every time I see tokens posted here, you'd be amazed how often they're actually real :)

Comment: It does seem to be something dangerous :D

Comment: Someone rated this question as something unimportant. That's interesting. This does raise my concern, and I'm sure others would also need to consider the problem. Somehow this is particular related to firebase as it has the firebaseAuthToken.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I would guess the person who did did it for lack of research/effort. The topic is important enough.

Comment: Once again, thank you so much.

Comment: Great question @Ming. Your question was probably downvoted because this is ostensibly about how OAuth works, and what the security risks of OAuth are; probably worthy of a chapter or perhaps entire book. We'll give it the old college try, though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fundamentally a question about OAuth and how it operates. The generation of an encrypted token is fundamental to this process. There are plenty of opinions on whether and where it is okay to store this token (cookies, local storage, memory, etc).

Is a token secure? When utilized over an SSL session, OAuth is quite secure. Firebase utilizes the same OAuth practices and encryptions that the other big names, all of whom provide OAuth tokens in a similar manner (in fact, in Simple Login, you can obtain your Facebook auth token, for instance, as part of the login payload, exactly as it's given to us via Facebook's API).

That's not to say that OAuth is without its warts. There is no perfect answer in security since everything is a trade-off. The only completely secure system is the one that doesn't exist physically, isn't connected to any network, and can't be accessed by human beings.

Regarding XSS, etc: In essence, once the trolls are in the castle, the china is going to get broken. If the client is compromised, then nothing is secure. If a user manages to somehow compromise your client's browser or execute a successful XSS, then they can gain access to your account by a number of ways, regardless of whether we're talking OAuth tokens or plain login/password fields.

In summary, if you trust Google, Facebook, Twitter, Yahoo, and M$ authentication to be relatively secure, then you can have the same faith in the Firebase authentication schema.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This helps me to understand more about OAuth.

The OAuth solution provided by Firebase is my first attempt in the OAuth area, (and it's great!) so I need more investigation to find out how much people can make use of these tokens.

When I use OAuth on any website, they always tell people that all the contacts related to the logged in account become available to the system. 

The fact that all these websites get are just these tokens makes me feel that a client side application with a possibility to expose all of these is scary (A server side backend would have no problem)

Answer (score 2):

To provide more answers to my own question so that it can be beneficial for other people who come across the same question, I tried to log in, log out, log in again. Each time I get different tokens (for both: accessToken, firebaseAuthToken). So these tokens act like sessionId and would expire when logging out.

Found an answer from Andrew Lee from Firebase. He explains that the tokens are time-bound and can be kept in browser localStorage (and this is how we suppose to maintain an active session).

Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14094165/2810746