# Android :: How to automatically re-authenticate the User when the token expires (Email + Password authentication)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase in my Android notepad app. I enabled Disk persistence and I am using Email + Password to authenticate users. Everything seems to work fine but I noticed that when the app is offline for a certain amount of time, users have to re-authenticate. Is there a way to automatically re-authenticate users when the auth token expires ?

Comment: Cross post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/Y5r9ufAcE8k

Comment: Yeah I am sorry. U just wanted to get an answer quickly that's why I cross posted 

Comment: It's not wrong to cross post with an external site. As long as you communicate any good answers from one site back to the other site, I'd say you're ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Authentication does not automatically refresh tokens.

If you'd be using one of the OAuth providers, you could probably catch the event when the token is about to expire, refresh it and then call `authWithCustomToken` again.

But given that you're using email+password authentication, there is nothing you can do but authenticate the user again (if you decide to hang on to their username/password in the app) or have them authenticate again. Also see: [Session management with Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094010/session-management-with-firebase)

Comment: Thank you . I think I should find a way to re-authenticate the user myself. Android as an API to store user credentials I could use that to store and retrieve the credentials and re-authenticate the user automatically when the token has expired

Comment: If you are speaking about Android's AccountManager yes, it's the safest place to store credentials. Anyway, consider that on a rooted phone that data will be easly be accessibile